# Notify create pointer class A to specific instance of class B1 or B2 or B3

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
class Propulsion () {}; //abstract
class GenericDualMotor : public Propulsion {}; // also abstract
class Motor1 : public GenericDualMotor () {}; // Concrete
class Motor2 : public GenericDualMotor () {}; // Concrete
class Motor3 : public GenericDualMotor () {}; // Concrete

class Dispatcher { // concrete but not a descendant of Propulsion
public:
    template<class T>
    T *_motor;
    Dispatcher(T motor) : _motor(motor){};

    void forward() {
       _motor->forward();
    }
};
```

the "forward" method is declared in Propulsion as:

```
virtual void forward(int speed) = 0; // abstract
```

But in each Motor class, it is declared as concrete:

```
void forward(int speed) {
     // motor-specific code here...
}
```

in Main, I declare:

```
Motor1 motor();
Dispatcher dispatcher(&motor);
```

This fails to compile with the notice: "error: data member '_motor' cannot be a member template"

What I want to do is decide at compile time which motor type is being used and be able to add new motor types without changing the Dispatcher or GenericDualMotor class code. I suspect that template is the correct mechanism to use here, but I still don't fully "grok" templates. And I imagine this is a simple code fix. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: a non static template member ? (What is the size of the class ?)

Comment: You don't need a template, the `virtual` will do the magic.

Comment: Why T* instead of Propulsion*?

Comment: Jarod - There are over 25 classes in my solution so far. Four of them are "motor" driver classes. 
tkaus - please say more about the virtual solution. Note that Dispatcher is not a descendant of Propulsion. They are entirely separate; hence my need to inform Dispatcher which motor is being used.

Comment: `Motor1 motor();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Throwing in an alternate idea: If you use a current compiler, instead of building a class hierarchy, you could as well consider to use lambda functions (or std::function) to pass concrete motor behavior to the types which need it.

Comment: Actually, I am doing all this for an Arduino platform which doesn't support the std function. But thanks for the idea. And since I am studying Uncle Bob Martin's Agile book, most of this is about finding the cleanest and best way to design and implement this problem. So far, I have rewritten the entire code 3 times!

Comment: Motor1 motor(56,7,8...) is actually a constructor... now that I have fixed that. See my revised code.

Comment: @BobJones Where did `PropulsionSystem` come from? I'm reverting your edit as it fixes no existing problems with the question and adds new conflicting information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the type of thing that polymorphism is meant for.  No template is needed.

```
class Propulsion {
public:
    virtual ~Propulsion() {}
    virtual void forward(int speed) = 0;
};

class GenericDualMotor : public Propulsion {
};

class Motor1 : public GenericDualMotor {
public:
    void forward(int speed);
};

class Motor2 : public GenericDualMotor {
public:
    void forward(int speed);
};

class Motor3 : public GenericDualMotor {
public:
    void forward(int speed);
};

class Dispatcher {
public:
    Propulsion *_motor;
    Dispatcher(Propulsion *motor) : _motor(motor) {};

    void forward() {
       _motor->forward(some speed value here);
    }
};
```

```
Motor1 motor;
Dispatcher dispatcher(&motor);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need templates - that's the point of having a `virtual` function. Just have:

```
class Dispatcher { // concrete but not a descendant of Propulsion
public:
    Propulsion* _motor;
    Dispatcher(Propulsion* motor) : _motor(motor){};

    void forward(int speed) {
       _motor->forward(speed);
    }
};
```

This will work with anything that inherits from `Propulsion`, including all of your `Motor`s.